# Are ZipFile InputStreams thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, zip

I cannot find any statement that specifies whether it would be safe to get multiple `InputStream`s (from multiple `ZipEntry`'s) and process each in its own thread.

Would this be safe to attempt?

Would it be advisable?

**Added**

Might I get better performance this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading should be OK. Each stream contains its own state, so you can open multiple streams that point to the same file and read from them concurrently.

But simultaneous writing is wrong. It will create mismatch in your file.

Comment: +1: I would use a different InputStream in each thread. Sharing an InputStream between threads is also likely to cause problems.

Comment: Is there any documentation to support this? Remember that each stream (and therefore all threads) will share a `ZipFile` object. ... I wouldn't dream of trying to write in parallel.

Comment: I tried it ... it worked ... but it did not improve performance. In fact it decreased performance by 50%.

Answer (score 3):

`ZipFile` InputStreams should be threadsafe, but the `ZipFile` API itself is instance-synchronized (internally all the reading/writing methods, including for reading metadata, are isolated using `synchronized (this)`), so `ZipFile` instances can be accessed by only one thread at a time.

If you want multiple threads to read from the same zipfile in a scalable way, you must open one `ZipFile` instance per thread, with each thread reading from separate InputStreams, each one derived from a different `ZipEntry`. That way, the per-thread lock in the `ZipFile` methods does not block all but one thread from reading from the zipfile at one time. It also means that when each thread closes the `ZipFile` after they're done reading, they close their own instance, not the shared instance, so you don't get an exception on the second and subsequent close.

Protip: if you really care about speed, and you need multiple threads reading from the same `ZipFile`, you can get more performance by reading all the `ZipEntry` objects from the first ZipFile instance, and sharing them with all threads, to avoid duplicating work in reading the zipfile central directory for each thread separately. A `ZipEntry` object is not tied to a specific `ZipFile` instance per se, `ZipEntry` just records metadata that will work with any `ZipFile` object representing the same zipfile that the `ZipEntry` came from. So this is the recipe for scaling up `ZipFile` usage in Java:

1. Open N `ZipFile` instances on the file, one for each of the `N` worker threads.
2. For just one of the `ZipFile` instances, read all the `ZipEntry` objects, and store in a list.
3. Distribute the list of `ZipEntry` objects to each of the `N` worker threads, along with the thread's own unique `ZipFile` instance.
4. In parallel, within each thread, open an `InputStream` on the thread's `ZipFile` instance, using whatever `ZipEntry` objects you want that thread to open (e.g. you could instruct each thread to open just one of the files). Or you could put all the `ZipEntry` objects into a concurrent queue or parallel stream, and all the worker threads could consume entries from the queue, if you want just one thread to open each `ZipEntry`, while load-leveling as well as possible.
5. When each thread has finished, it should close its own `ZipFile` instance.

Answer (score 1):

[TrueVFS](https://truevfs.java.net/) (the successor of [TrueZIP](https://truezip.java.net/)) can read and write a ZIP file threadsave.

Comment: Do you achieve better performance with reading or writing from multiple threads?